# Is this how you download a file from HTTP?

Tags: java, android, http, download, buffer

After reading Tutorials on the internet I came up with this function for downloading a sound file from HTTP:

```
        try {
            URL url = new URL(filePath);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            File storage = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            File directory = new File(storage.getAbsolutePath());
            directory.mkdirs();

            file = new File(directory, fileName + ".mp3");

            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

             totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            int downloadedSize = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer


            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                Log.i("download:", downloadedSize + "/" + totalSize);
            }

            fileOutput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
```

It works fine on my device and on all kind of emulators but some users complain about not beeing able to download the file.
Is there something I'm missing? Why is it working on my device but is failing on a few others?
Would be glad if someone could look over it and tell me if this is done correctly.

Comment: `directory.mkdirs();` Wrong. That should be `if ( !directory.exists()) if ( !  directory.mkdirs()) return;` Care for the directory before you start the download. And if the directory does not exists do not start the download. How do you know now that a directory could not be created?

Comment: `catch (IOException e)` It is good that you catch exceptions. But now... if there is an exception... how do you shouw the exception message `e.getMessage()` to the user?

Answer (score 0):

`urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);`

is incorrect. You are not sending content to the server.

Comment: okay thanks, urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");  as well?

Comment: Should be the default if you remove the "setDoOutput()".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because other people's mobile phone system versions are different, and the APIs are also different. You need to adapt to a newer version of the mobile phone system